# Is gas or fees required for creating an assosiate token account?

Tags: associated-token-account, spl-associated-token-account, fees

Is gas or fees required for creating an assosiate token account?

Or can it be created without any gas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a little bit of SOL to pay the "rent" to create the token account, however this SOL can also be recovered when you close the token account. I believe its around 0.002 SOL

Comment: Will a tx itself require paying gas too?

Comment: yea there's also the tx fee to send a transaction that includes the instruction to create the token account

Comment: Just to add up you can only close the token account if its balance is 0.

Comment: What's "just to add up" for? @AbdullahQureshi I already see that you've added something up.